# Change image button in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got an HTML option table where the user can add a row by clicking on add button:

```js
$('.NewImg').click(function() {
  var row = $(this).closest('tr').clone();
  row.find('input').val('');
  $(this).closest('tr').after(row);
  $('input[type="image"]', row).removeClass('AddNew').addClass('RemoveRow');
});

$('table').on('click', '.RemoveRow', function() {
  $(this).closest('tr').remove();
});
// everytime the save button is clicked
$('#savebutton').click(function() {
  saveList();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="multiselect" id="order-list">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <label>Studio:</label>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <select class="studio">
        <option>-- Select Studio --</option>
        <?php $resultStudio=g etStudioID(); while ($row=m ysqli_fetch_array($resultStudio)) { echo "<option value = '".$row[ 'studio_name']. "'>".$row[ 'studio_name']. "</option>"; } ?>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input id="addrow" class='NewImg' type="image" src="img/add.png" alt="Submit" onClick="return false;" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <a class="deleteRow"></a>

    </td>
    <!--<td><input type='button' class='AddNew' value='Add new item' /></td>-->
  </tr>
</table>
```

How can I change the image in js code? When a row is added I've still got a "+" image, however, I want to change it to a "-" image

Answer (score 0):

Use `toggleClass`

```
 $('input[type="image"]', row).toggleClass('AddNew RemoveRow');
```

add a different background to each class

Answer (score 0):

there is no predefined attribute called scr for input. You can use css to add image on button.

Try this

```
<button type="button" style="background: url('img/add.png') no-repeat;">+</button>
```

Comment: where should i put this?

Comment: There is a type image input to be used as submit button where you can set an src attribute. I think is the method @Yevgeniy is using http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_src.asp

Answer (score 0):

With your own code which I would refactor a lot:

Notice the: `.attr('src', 'img/remove.png')`

Obviously you need a `remove.png` image in the `img` directory

```js
$('.NewImg').click(function() {
  var row = $(this).closest('tr').clone();
  row.find('input').val('');
  $(this).closest('tr').after(row);
  $('input[type="image"]', row).removeClass('AddNew').addClass('RemoveRow').attr('src', 'img/remove.png');
});

$('table').on('click', '.RemoveRow', function() {
  $(this).closest('tr').remove();
});
// everytime the save button is clicked
$('#savebutton').click(function() {
  saveList();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="multiselect" id="order-list">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <label>Studio:</label>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <select class="studio">
        <option>-- Select Studio --</option>
        <?php $resultStudio=g etStudioID(); while ($row=m ysqli_fetch_array($resultStudio)) { echo "<option value = '".$row[ 'studio_name']. "'>".$row[ 'studio_name']. "</option>"; } ?>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input id="addrow" class='NewImg' type="image" src="img/add.png" alt="Submit" onClick="return false;" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <a class="deleteRow"></a>

    </td>
    <!--<td><input type='button' class='AddNew' value='Add new item' /></td>-->
  </tr>
</table>
```